# How to record last X hours of a live stream via FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

In normal case, saving a live stream in a local file is easy. But I'm looking for a way to keep last X amount of time of the stream. i.e last 2 days.

Obviously the file must be updated constantly.

Any help? Thanks.